# Shifted Chebyshev polynomials in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to extract the coefficients of a shifted Chebyshev Polynomial in Python, but I couldn't find the function to do that.

There is this function:

```
scipy.special.eval_sh_chebyt

scipy.special.eval_sh_chebyt(n, x, out=None) = <ufunc 'eval_sh_chebyt'>
```

but I can't extract only the coefficients.

The shifted Chebyshev polynomials are:
T^{*}_n(x) = T_n (2x -1)

and then:

T_1^{*}(x) = 2x - 1

T_2^{*}(x) = 8x^2 - 8x -1

I would like to extract a matrix only with the coefficients, like 2 and 1 or 8,8 and 1.

Comment: Can you post the input you are giving to function?

Comment: T = scipy.special.eval_sh_chebyt, then I want to do say chebyshev order of 10 and extract only the coefficients

Comment: You can pass `n` and `x` to the function where `n` is *Degree of the polynomial. If not an integer, the result is determined via the relation* and `x` is *Points at which to evaluate the shifted Chebyshev polynomial* so what is the value of `n` and `x` when you say **chebyshev order of 10**

Comment: Is there a need to use that scipy function?

Comment: but I need a matrix only with the coefficients. If you could write down your example I would appreciate.

Comment: `special.eval_sh_chebyt([2,1],10)` I am getting result `array([721.,  19.])` if you do `result  = special.eval_sh_chebyt([2,1],10)` then `result[0]` will give you coeff 721 and `result[1]` will give 19

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article _T1 = x_ and _T2 = 2x² - 1_.

Comment: Thus _T1* = 2x² - x_ and _T2* = 4x³ - 2x² - 2x + 1_.

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari seems that 721 and 19 are the final result when you apply 10 at x. I would like to get the coefficients before apply a value for x. Example: For T_2(x) = 8x^2 - 8x +1, I would like to get a vector with these coefficients. Your answer seems to be the final result, not the first coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.special.eval_sh_chebyt` evaluates the function *T** at a given point *x*. Unless you are very smart in choosing your arguments, this is not an appropriate way to get the coeffcients.

You can instead calculate the coefficients directly from the recurrence formula *T0 = 1, T1 = x, T{n} = 2xT{n-1} - T{n-2}*. And then calculate the shifted polynomials from _T*{n} = T{n}(2x - 1).

```
degree = 10

coeffs = []
# for T_0
coeffLine = [1]
coeffs.append(coeffLine)
# for T_1
coeffLine = [0, 1]
coeffs.append(coeffLine)

for i in range(2, degree + 1):
    coeffLine = [0] * (1 + i)
    coeffLine[0] = -coeffs[i - 2][0]
    for j in range(1, i - 1):
        coeffLine[j] = 2 * coeffs[i - 1][j - 1] - coeffs[i - 2][j]
    coeffLine[-2] = 2 * coeffs[i - 1][-2]
    coeffLine[-1] = 2 * coeffs[i - 1][-1]
    coeffs.append(coeffLine)        

print("T_%d" % degree, coeffs[-1])

shiftedCoeffs = [0] * (degree + 1);
for i in range(degree + 1):
    binom = 1
    for j in range(i + 1):
        shiftedCoeffs[i - j] += coeffs[-1][i] * 2 ** (i - j) * (-1) ** j * binom
        binom *= (i - j) / (j + 1)


print("T*_%d" % degree, shiftedCoeffs)
```

**Edit:** I originally misread the formula for *T*{n}* as _T{n}(x) * (2x - 1). However it is *T*{n} = T{n}(2x - 1)*. We therefore need to calculate the binomial coefficients sum them up depending on the order of *x*.

Comment: This is not the correct way to do that. The relation is not that simple. We need to do the Newton Binomial in order to get that relation. Your code gives to the shiftedcoeffs the following answer: [[-1, 2], [0, -1, 2], [1, -2, -2, 4], [0, 3, -6, -4, 8], [-1, 2, 8, -16, -8, 16], [0, -5, 10, 20, -40, -16, 32], [1, -2, -18, 36, 48, -96, -32, 64], [0, 7, -14, -56, 112, 112, -224, -64, 128], [-1, 2, 32, -64, -160, 320, 256, -512, -128, 256], [0, -9, 18, 120, -240, -432, 864, 576, -1152, -256, 512]], which is not the correct one. Thanks for your trying.

Comment: So what are the correct polynomials? Edit: I see, It's T_n(2x-1) not T_n(x)*(2x-1).